# Expected $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ for a phenotypic trait, given heritability h and known parental phenotypic measures?

Tags: genetics

Say a measurable phenotypic trait has mean $\mu =0$, variance $\sigma^2 = 1$, and [heritability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heritability) $h$, meaning that h*100% of the variation in the population is caused by genetic variation and (1-h)*100% is caused by environmental factors whether shared or unshared.

We define "standard environment" as an environment in which the contribution made by each environmental feature, whether shared and unshared, is at the population mean for the contribution made by that feature.

Clearly if we take individuals in the population at random their expected mean measurement is 0 and their expected standard deviation is 1.

But say we have two parents whose phenotypic measurements for the trait are respectively $p_1$ and $p_2$. Then **what will the expected mean and standard deviation for their offspring be if their offspring's environment is standard?** I am interested in the general case, but even an answer only for the case $p_1 = p_2$ would be helpful. I would also be interested to know whether the answer might reasonably be expected to vary according to whether the parental phenotypic measurements are or are not significantly different from what would be expected from their own genes.

From a "pure mathematical" point of view, the answer is "we can't tell", because for example the expected mean measurement might be 0 for all individuals except those who have both parents with genes determining an expected measurement greater than 3 or smaller than -3. So please make (and state if possible) whatever assumptions seem reasonable.

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so it should be tagged as such.

Comment: No, it isn't...